# Ngnix: Multiple Websites Using a Shared IP on a Server with Multiple IP Adress

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am deploying multiple websites to an Ubuntu server equipped with Nginx. I also use the `proxy_pass` feature to pass the traffic to the service.

The problem is whichever websites is set on Nginx first, all incoming traffics are rerouted to.

I created 3 different `.conf` files in `/etc/nginx/conf` and here is the details for each:

- *subdomain1.conf*

```
server {
listen       <the second ip>:80;
server_name  subdomain1.mydomain.com;

location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:11111;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

- *subdomain2.conf*

```
server {
listen       <the second ip>:80;
server_name  subdomain2.mydomain.com;

location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:22222;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

- *subdomain3.conf*

```
server {
listen       <the second ip>:80;
server_name  subdomain3.mydomain.com;

location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:33333;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Finally, I reload Nginx using the following command line:
`sudo nginx -s reload`

However, all incoming traffics for other subdomains (subdomain2 and subdomain3) are somehow passed to subdomain1. What I have noted so far is whichever set first, all incoming traffics are bound to it.

Comment: Can you use `listen 80;` instead of `listen <the second ip>:80;`?

Comment: It didn't work. Seemingly, I can't have more than 1 "server" defined and I should only use "location" to distinguish requests which is very odd.

Comment: So as for solution, I just added static IP addresses

Comment: What happens if you put all three server blocks in a single .conf file instead? I have a similar setup with multiple subdomains on the same IP and it works fine.

Comment: @miknik It would be awesome if you could share it. However, I am setting up a pipeline and it would be very difficult to write a bash script to handle such a circumstance.

Comment: My conf file is super long, but the only difference is I have a server block at the start which is for the root domain with no subdomain and in the `listen` directives I dont specify an IP address, just the port. I'm also using SSL for them all.